# How to run make recursively with only one parralel job?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile which runs other makefiles. One of those other makefiles is buggy, sometimes it fails if run with `-j 2` or more. How can I recursively invoke that makefile allowing it to have only one job, no parallelism? I usually run my outer makefile with `-j 9`.

Comment: and invoking the inner make as `$(MAKE) -j1 <etc>` doesn't do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `-j1` to make command line running your makefile will definitely work. However I'd suggest to fix problem in a different way.

Q: Who is trouble maker?

A: Makefile with wrong dependencies in rules.

So the right solution would be to fix the makefile. The simplest fix would be just adding special `.NOTPARALLEL` target.

GNU Make manual https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html:

> .NOTPARALLEL is mentioned as a target, then this invocation of make
>   will be run serially, even if the ‘-j’ option is given. Any
>   recursively invoked make command will still run recipes in parallel
>   (unless its makefile also contains this target). Any prerequisites on
>   this target are ignored.

So just add

```
# TBD: This makefile is broken: it doesn't support -j make option.
.NOTPARALLEL:
```

to trouble makefile and don't touch command line running it. Doing it this way will be self-documenting workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing adding option `-j1` like this `$(MAKE) -C ${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR} -j1 install` works.